Login Form PyQt6
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog,
    QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QMessageBox)

class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textName = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textPass = QLineEdit(self)
        self.buttonLogin = QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textName)
        layout.addWidget(self.textPass)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)

    def handleLogin(self):
        if (self.textName.text() == 'foo' and
            self.textPass.text() == 'bar'):
            self.accept()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Error', 'Bad user or password')

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        # self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login()

    if login.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())

Returns:
AttributeError: 'Login' object has no attribute 'QDialog' 
Apparently it worked with PyQT5 but not pyQT6? What changes need to be done to get this to work? TIA.

The provided code should not and does not result in that error. It has another issue, though, which is the wrong syntax of QDialog.Accepted: since PyQt6 all enums must use their full namespace, meaning that it should be QDialog.DialogCode.Accepted. With that change, there is no error, leading me to think that that code is not the one causing that error. In any case, provide the full traceback (consider running it in a terminal or prompt, as IDEs are not always able to show the complete traceback).
